# How do I convert these multiple lists into a big dictionary using python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
subjects = ['Chem', 'Phy', 'Math']
students = ['Joy', 'Agatha', 'Mary', 'Frank', 'Godwin', 'Chizulum', 'Enoc', 'Chinedu', 'Kenneth', 'Lukas']
math = [76,56,78,98,88,75,59,80,45,30]
phy  = [72,86,70,98,89,79,69,50,85,80]
chem  = [75,66,77,45,83,75,59,40,65,90]
```

How do I transform the lists above to the nested dictionary below using pyhon

```
{
'math':{'joy':76, 'Agatha':56, 'Mary':78.....},
'phy':{'joy':72, 'Agatha':86, 'Mary':70....},
'chem':{'joy':75, 'Agatha':66, 'Mary':77....}
}
```

Comment: Do you really receive those lists like that, meaning: is part of your assignment to get from an list entry like "Chem" ... to know that there is another list named "chem" that has the grades of the students like that?

Comment: And note: you learn programming by ... programming. Not by making it your first impulse to ask others to do the thinking and working for you. So: when asking about homework, you are encouraged to include your own efforts. As in: for sure, you got material for your class ... so, have you studied that, and tried to think of a solution yourself?

Comment: you will find the `zip` function useful https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 0):

With the given lists, you could build the result dictionary this way :

```
result_dict = {
    subject: {
        name: grade for name in students for grade in globals()[subject.lower()]
    }
    for subject in subjects
}
```

This solution uses a nested dictionary comprehension and isn't meant for beginners. On top of that the use of built-in `globals()` is not recommanded and only suits in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly not the most elegant way to do this, but it works:

```
dictionary = {}

dict_math = {}
dict_phy = {}
dict_chem = {}
for i in range(len(students)):
    dict_math[students[i]] = math[i]
    dict_phy[students[i]] = phy[i]
    dict_chem[students[i]] = chem[i]

dictionary['math'] = dict_math
dictionary['phy'] = dict_phy
dictionary['chem'] = dict_chem

print(dictionary)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
math_grades = list(zip(students, math))
phy_grades = list(zip(students, phy))
chem_grades = list(zip(students, chem))

your_dict = {
      "math": {c: d for c, d in math_grades},
      "phy": {c: d for c, d in phy_grades},
      "chem": {c: d for c, d in chem_grades},
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
subjects = ['Chem', 'Phy', 'Math']
students = ['Joy', 'Agatha', 'Mary', 'Frank', 'Godwin', 'Chizulum', 'Enoc', 'Chinedu', 'Kenneth', 'Lukas']
math = [76, 56, 78, 98, 88, 75, 59, 80, 45, 30]
phy = [72, 86, 70, 98, 89, 79, 69, 50, 85, 80]
chem = [75, 66, 77, 45, 83, 75, 59, 40, 65, 90]

grades = {
      "math": dict(zip(students, math)),
      "phy": dict(zip(students, phy)),
      "chem": dict(zip(students, chem)),
}
```